# Is it better to create new fields in post table in Wordpress or create new table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, custom-fields

I'm quite new to using Wordpress and have problem to figure out what solution to choose.

I have to store over 200.000 entries (books, cds,...) in the posts table of Wordpress. Each of those entries have about 20 different fields to populate.

Therefore, I think I'll have to add new fields to the posts table so store the data.

I'm using the ACF custom fields plugin to do so, but I can see that the custom fields are not stored in the same table as the post table. It's being stored in wp_options table for the categories and in postmeta table for the posts and for each of the fields to populate it will create 2 lines in these tables.

So if I save 20 fields X 2 lines X 200.000 entries in this wp_postmeta table, it will make 8.000.000 lines to go through (maybe not that good for performances).

What would be the best way to achieve this task using Wordpress ?

- Create a new table ? (I'll not take benefit of the regular post features and cache possibilities)
- Add new fields to the post table ? (will it be compatible with upgrade of WP ?)
- Use postmeta/option tables ? (what about performances in this case ?) and go ahead with this solution ?

Many thanks by advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are pros and cons to each of the approaches you list:

---

> Create a new table ? (I'll not take benefit of the regular post features and cache possibilities)

**Pro:** Performance
**Con:** Flexibility, Features

**Flexibility** By create a table with columns for each of your fields you lose flexibility. It is harder to add new fields compared to just using meta data. For tables with a large number of rows, adding or removing columns is an expensive operation so if you need to modify your schema frequently this might not be the way to go.

**Features** Using this approach you won't be able to utilize the built in methods for interacting with meta data (ex `get_post_meta`). You will also have a harder time querying posts based on your meta data. You can still cache your data, but you will have to do it manually. You *will not* be able to continue using ACF with this approach as far as I am aware.

**Performance** On the positive side, having each of your fields as a column in a separate table allows you to better index your data. Whether or not this will work to your advantage depends on the queries you need to run.

---

> Use postmeta/option tables ? (what about performances in this case ?) and go ahead with this solution ?

**Con:** Flexibility, Features
**Pro:** Performance

Obviously if you stick with the default method for handling meta data, you can continue to use all of the built-in features for interacting with that data. You'll also be able to add or remove meta fields without altering your table structure.

Regarding performance, you aren't going to be able to create indexes to improve the performance of your queries like you would with a separate table. This is only a serious problem if your queries cannot take advantage of the indexes on the postmeta table.

Note that `wp_postmeta` has indexes on the `post_id` and the `meta_key`, but not the `meta_value`. This means that if you are looking up records based on the meta value and you have a lot of rows that share the same meta key, the database has to look through all of the rows with a particular meta key to find the ones with the meta value you are looking for.

> So if I save 20 fields X 2 lines X 200.000 entries in this wp_postmeta table, it will make 8.000.000 lines to go through

This may not be a serious problem depending on your queries. As I mentioned before, the postmeta table has an index on the `post_id` so if you are only looking up meta entries by `post_id` this isn't a serious problem.

8 million rows is not a problem for MySQL so long as your queries can utilize an index.

If you are just querying based on `post_id` indexes aren't an issue. As far as memory goes, you're going to need roughly the same amount of memory regardless of which approach you use.

---

> Add new fields to the post table ? (will it be compatible with upgrade of WP ?)

This approach is going to be pretty much the same as creating a separate table:

- You will have a greater ability to improve performance by indexing
  your posts table
- You will not be able to utilize built-in features
  for interacting with meta data
- Adding and removing fields will be more difficult

I don't *think* this will cause an issue with upgrading WordPress. Even if an upgrade includes modifications to the `wp_posts` table, having additional columns *shouldn't* cause problems. I would definitely test upgrades in a staging environment before upgrading in production.

In general I think it is best to avoid modifying core WordPress functionality, including modifying the default table structures. This approach isn't going to have any significant performance advantages compared to having a separate table so I think it is best to go another way.

Comment: A very bad and wrong answer about performance.  An index does not keep the data so you have n more disk accesses instead of using a n-column table. But 8 million data cells is just not a lot and fits well into even small VPS RAM. Unless the data is very different for a lot of items, it's better to store it in extra tables. Or if the additional data fields are not required for searching use a JSON object to store it all in one meta data.

Comment: @Lothar Regarding creating additional tables, is that not what I said? It's more performant to create additional tables in general, but this is not how WordPress works out of the box. At the time this was written ACF did not provide any features for working with additional tables and as far as I'm aware that is not something that is currently supported either. If you create additional tables you're going to lose all of the features ACF provides which is going to cost a significant amount of development time.